# make numname and enumitem work together

Tags: memoir, enumerate, enumitem

[`numname`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numname) is a package that allows you to write out (e.g.) chapter titles in words. It's basically some code taken out of `memoir.cls` apparently.

There appears to be something wrong with the code, however.

I tried to make an option to have `enumerate`'s with word labels like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{numname}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nthwords}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@nthwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@nthwords}[1]{%
  \ordinaltoName{#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\nthwords}{\@nthwords}{eleven}

\makeatother

\newcounter{tctr}
\setcounter{tctr}{12}

\begin{document}
\nthwords{tctr}

% \begin{enumerate}[label=\nthwords*]
% \item Boo
% \item Far
% \item Faz\label{fz}
% \end{enumerate}
% \ref{fz}

\end{document}
```

This works fine, but uncommenting out the enumerate environment makes it complain about an "`incomplete \iffalse`" at the line with the first `\item`.

Now, commenting out `\usepackage{numname}` and changing the documentclass to `memoir` fixes things.

So *something* has gone wrong. Any clues as to what that might be? Or should I email the author of numname? [I ask because I know we have some `memoir` experts who might be able to spot the problem...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really work with memoir and you'll see it by adding a `\label` to the second item and a `\ref` to it.

You can get it to work by

```
\usepackage{numname}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nthwords}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@nthwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@nthwords}[1]{%
  \protect\ordinaltoName{\number#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\nthwords}{\@nthwords}{eleven}
\makeatother
```

The reason why **memoir** doesn't give an error is because `\ordinaltoName` is robust in that class and it isn't for **numname**.